# How to change Firebase user login identity from command line (CLI)?

Tags: command-line, firebase, command-line-interface

I'm trying to login to Firebase using login credentials of, let's say, **User-Alice**.

But when I go through the authorization procedure I get a message saying I'm logged in as **User-Bob**. [This is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/command-line-tool.html) nor does it explain how to change the user I'm logged in as.

How can I change the Firebase logged in user from **User-Bob** to **User-Alice**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 399, accepted):

**Manage multiple users via the CLI**

You can manage multiple users without re-authenticating, as of version [9.9.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#cli_v9-9-0) of the Firebase CLI.

```
firebase login:add
firebase login:list
firebase login:use
```

Example:

```
firebase login:add david@example.com
firebase login:add alice@example.com
firebase login:add bob@example.com
firebase login:use alice@example.com
firebase login:list
firebase deploy --only hosting # deploy as alice@example.com
```

**Get a URL printed to the terminal.**

```
firebase login --reauth
```

Use that link in the browser with the needed profile.

---

**Still working, less convenient older answer**

The easiest way to handle this is to logout User-Alice and the login User-Bob.

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```

But, if you're logged as User-Alice with a Google account in the browser you'll need to sign out there first.

Comment: Please give me a little more detail. When I try that, it logs me back in as User A. That's the whole point of the question. There is no way to specify which user to login. The key that is generated is somehow tied to a different user and I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Does it open up the browser to log you with your Google account? Or are you logging in via the command-line with user and password?

Comment: It opens a browser and forces me to login with the Google account. But it says my credentials are not authorized when I log in as the user I want. There is a link in the CLI instructions that when I copy and paste in a browser, it logs me in as the wrong user. Even when I'm using a browser under which I'm logged in as the user I want, it still registers the wrong user.

Comment: Ah, I just encountered this. You need to log out of the user in the browser as well. Otherwise it will just automatically log you in as that user every time.

Comment: Its not correct answer. `firebase login --reauth`  is correct answer which is answered by @john lee (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981675/10787285)

Comment: This answer is 5+ years old and was the only solution at the time and it still works but reauth is much easier if you're managing multiple browser profiles.

Comment: recent firebase added the feature of multiple login, as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/68572777/3090068

Answer (score 46):

use this

```
firebase login --reauth
```

then you can change account

Comment: Great suggestion. Just a note... this will generate a URL. You copy and paste that into a browser window. It will prompt you to enter different credentials. Once logged in, the CLI is now using that account.

Comment: I had the same problem and following your suggestion worked. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 16):

In the recent release of Firebase CLI (9.9.0) there was support for multiple accounts via new commands:

- **login:use**
- **login:add**
- **login:list**

Reference: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/tree/v9.9.0

So I used ***firebase login:add*** to add a new account and then switched to newly added account use ***firebase login:use***

Comment: This should be top answer, Thanks man saved my time

Answer (score 11):

Command for logout and login

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```

refer this link for more commands

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools

Answer (score 5):

You can get token string by this command.

```
firebase login:ci
```

Then set it to `FIREBASE_TOKEN` env.

You can keep any number of tokens and set it automatically by some utils like dotenv.

Comment: The normal logout-then-login approach causes the web page pop up for auth, then a security warning email (which also gets sent to any linked accounts) and then a security warning on your phone. This approach removes all of that, so switching is a breeze.

Comment: although token approach is deprecated

Comment: also this kind of approach is helpful when you are not creating firebase project via init and just using CLI for appdistribution

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few solutions:

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```

Or,

```
firebase login --reauth
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your currently log in Google account must include `'User Alice'(userAlice@gmail.com)` in your **default** browser. 
When you `firebase logout` and then Firebase will say

```
$ firebase logout
Logged out form 'userBob@gmail.com'
```

`firebase login`, Firebase will open a browser and get the comfirmation (allow or deny). When you accept/allow, you can see the following in your terminal.

```
$ firebase login
Allow Firebase to collect anonymous CLI usage information? Yes

Visit this URL on any device to log in:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=....

Waiting for authentication...

Success! Logged in as 'userAlice@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
firebase login:add
firebase login:list
firebase login:use youremail
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to log out of Google Accounts **in (using) your primary browser** (say, Safari). And log in to that same browser as the correct user. Trying to login to secondary browsers (say, Opera or Chrome) won't work. It needs to be the same browser that Firebase CLI opens automatically after hitting `firebase login`. Secondary browsers will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different google accounts - I recommend you have different browser `user profiles` for it in `Google Chrome`.

Before you enter `firebase login`, make sure you **activate** the respective browser window with the desired `user profile`.

This way you will not have to enter passwords again when switching accounts.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, Try (In Windows Powershell):

`firebase login:ci --interactive`

It will generate a token that you will set in your subsequent instructions. i.e. To init,

```
firebase init --token "secret-token"
```